# can I customize my existing LibGDX project with the gds-setup.jar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I've created my game with Lib-GDX and I'm almost done! :D
the problem is that I forgot to include one of the `Third Party feature` in the initial GDX setup. Is there any way I can go back and include it, using the gds-setup.jar or any other way? Or must I go the super advanced way and create a new project and include the feature?

To be more precise I'm trying to include the `libGDX cross platform Facebook support`

Answer (score 2):

You can just add your 3d party stuff to the build.gradle file for your case your need this :

```
compile "de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook:gdx-facebook-core:1.1.1"
```

to be added to the dependencies, there is no need of creating new project with gdx-setup.jar

check this topic in the officiel wiki for more info :

**[Dependency management with Gradle](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle)**

Answer (score -1):

I just created a new project with gdx-setup.jar and added the Third Party Ext. I wanted. Once that was complete i copied the code that called the TPE in the gradle files and added them to my original game's gradle so for Example:

```
project(":android") {
apply plugin: "android"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
compile project(":core")
    compile "de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook:gdx-facebook-android:1.1.1"//this is what I needed to add
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}

project(":core") {
apply plugin: "java"


dependencies {
    compile "de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook:gdx-facebook-core:1.1.1"//this was what I needed to add
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
```

this was all in the main project's gradle folder.